# Axios request not sending expected cookie header to Django server

Tags: reactjs, django, cookies, axios, csrf

I'm trying to upload a file to a Django server using an Axios post request in a React app. The server expects a CSRF cookie to be included in the request headers.

The request already includes all the methods I could find for setting the cookie. Through `document.cookie`, setting `withCredential: true`, and specifying the `Cookie` header.

Here is my Axios request:

```
const onSubmit = async (data) => {
    const formData = new FormData()
    formData.append('file', data.file[0])

    const csrftoken = getCookie('csrftoken');
    document.cookie = `csrftoken=${csrftoken}`

    const res = await axiosInstance.post('/upload/', formData, {
        timeout: 0,
        headers: {
            'Cookie': `csrftoken=${csrftoken}`, 
            'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
            'x-csrftoken': csrftoken,
        },
        withCredentials: true,
    })

    console.log(res)
}
```

And here is my Django view:

```
def upload_file(request):
    form = UploadFileForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UploadFileForm(request.POST, request.FILES)

        if form.is_valid():
            file_id = save_file_to_database(request.FILES['file'])
            response = JsonResponse({'id': file_id}, status=201)
            return response
        else:
            response = HttpResponse({'message': 'Upload failed'}, status=400)
            return response

    return render(request, 'upload.html', {'form': form})
```

Also, I believe I have properly set the relevant Django settings in `settings.py`:

```
CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST = (
    "http://localhost:8000",
    "http://127.0.0.1:5173",
)

CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS = [
    "http://127.0.0.1:5173"
]

SESSION_COOKIE_SAMESITE = 'None'
```

What can I do to ensure that the CSRF cookie is included in the request headers or that the CSRF requirements are met some other way? Just to be sure, the route works if we add `@csrf_exempt` to the view, so it should really be a CSRF problem.

Answer (score 0):

You only need to include the token in the `formData`. No headers or cookie manipulations necessary:

```js
const onSubmit = async (data) => {
    const formData = new FormData()
    formData.append('file', data.file[0])
    formData.append('csrfmiddlewaretoken', getCookie('csrftoken'));

    const res = await axiosInstance.post('/upload/', formData, {
        timeout: 0,
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
        },
        withCredentials: true,
    })

    console.log(res)
}
```

Tip: Whenever you're unsure if cookies, headers, etc... are being sent, check the network tab in your browser's dev tools. If you see them in the "Request headers" section for a request, then they *are* being sent, and it means the issue is on the server side. In this case, for `multipart/form-data` Django expects the token in a `csrfmiddlewaretoken` form field. For an `application/json` request, you can use `X-CSRFToken` header instead.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I'm still getting a 403 with `CSRF cookie not set.`, though

Comment: @FelipeMartins sorry to hear that. Have you cleared cookies in your browser after setting `SESSION_COOKIE_SAMESITE = 'None'`? What does the SameSite column in Application > Cookies in your browser's dev tools say for the cookie?

Comment: I had cleared the cookies after changing the setting, but did that once more just to be sure. There were three cookies for the site before that, two named csrftoken and one named sessiontoken or something close to that. After cleaning and attempting to send the form no new cookies showed up. I'm checking them in Storage > Cookies > http://127.0.0.1:5173/ in Firefox's dev tools.